# Android GCM switch to another network

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I have succesfully got android gcm working on my local network. However I observe that my server url is a an ip address in the 192.168 range. When I register this device on the same network it registers succesfully and I can send messages to it. But after registration if I switch my device to another network and try to send a gcm message I observe it does not work. I dont understand why this is happening. According to the architecture the app contacts the application server only once. After that all messages are relayed through the Google server. So even though the ip address is a local one, once my device is registered I should be able to switch over to a different network

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:
1. Go to  https://code.google.com/apis/console/

1. Click on API Access
2. It will show you all key related to your account.
3. Go to they key you are using in your APP for GCM & check for refer:

it should be

```
Referers: Any referer allowed
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I am unable to find refer in the api console. Can you please tell me where exactly it is under api access?

Comment: Humm Ok Please look at this image : http://developer.android.com/images/gcm/gcm-api-key.png IP's : Any IP allowed. Hope this help